# Google chart to plot in Python (script for Android)

Tags: android, python, charts, google-visualization, pygooglechart

how can I plot a time series (assume a simple numpy array of random numbers) in python and ask to plot this using Google chart? 
I want to use this script on my Android device using qPython. I can already generate the vector of data I want to display but I think I need to display this data in the web browser using Google chart. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

based on jqplot, all you need is just json data type and then let the jqplot render your chart.